# How do I disable namespace abbreviation in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: What I want to disable...]

If I'm not mistaken, since Visual Studio 2015 there's some new feature that grays out *redundant parts of namespace usings*. Also, when you automatically add an using to some assembly member using *quick actions*, the grayed part is omitted.

For example, the whole `Whatever.Framework.Shared.Data.Mongo` would be added as just `Shared.Data.Mongo` when using *quick actions*.

Is it possible to completely disable this refactoring feature?

Comment: Where do you specify those using directives? At the top of the file or inside your namespace declaration?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm declaring them inside namespace declaration. You may argue that then it's useless, but I still prefer to leave the entire namespace path to avoid collisions

Answer (score -1):

You will see this even going back to Visual Studio 2012 (and possibly older) under the following circumstances:

```
namespace Test.Foo {
    using Test.Foo.Bar; // can write using Bar
    public class Class1 {
    }
}
```

vs

```
using Test.Foo.Bar;

namespace Test.Foo {
    public class Class1 {
    }
}
```

The first will grey out the `Test.Foo.` part in the using statement, as you are inside the `namespace` declaration. The second will not.

Comment: BTW in older versions it wasn't grayed out and it didn't omitted the "shared part of the namespace path"...

Comment: Sorry, its 2012 where it is greyed out (using it now to test).

Comment: The change from 2012/2013 is 2015 completely removes the grayed part by default when adding usings from *quick actions*. This is the most important part I would like to disable.

Comment: In that case move your using statements to the top of the file, outside the namespace declaration.

Comment: I believe this won't answer my issue at all. I knew for sure why VS grays out these usings. The issue is I want to disable this feature :D

Comment: And moving namespace declarations to the top of the file isn't the solution after all. I still prefer leaving the whole usings inside the namespace declaration. I know there's no performance improvement, but you know that then you're isolating where you use a namespace.

Comment: Quickadd works based on where you put your using statements, so if they are at the top it adds to whole namespace, if they are inside the namespace declaration then it just adds the required part (and not the simplified part). I haven't found a way to disable this, sorry.

Comment: BTW my concern isn't the gray color but that VS2015 omits the part that would be in gray when adding usings with quick actions... I believe you should drop your answer, and we should wait to find someone that could disable it. Sometimes there's a registry hack...

Comment: I'll leave it as I think it adds something to the conversation - you might want to update your question with that information though.